# How do I find the moment generating function of $N(0, 1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Here is my homework, I just don't really know how to find the moment generating function. I can do the rest after i get that. Any help? [image]

Comment: Write down the integral that defines the moment generating function of $N(0,1)$. Now see how it resembles the Gaussian integral,  subject to a completion of square in the exponent.

Comment: Hint: try to show that $Z_1^2 \sim\text{gamma}(\frac12,\frac12)$.

Comment: Just do the integral.. it's two lines and involves no completing the square (the MGF of $Z$ would involve completing the square.)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
A moment generating function is an expectation value you must take in one way or another. Here you want $$E(e^{tZ^2}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tz^2}\frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dz= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}(1-2t)z^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dz.$$ This integral is simple to do via a substitution, and to generalize to $Z_1^2+\ldots +Z_n^2.$ (The MGF of the sum of $n$ iids is just the MGF raised to the n-th power.)

Comment: So the mgf of Z^2 is e^(t^2)?

Comment: No... that's not what that comes out to. It's just a substitution for the scalar multiple $(2t-1)^{1/2}$

Comment: So then the mgf is just 1/(2t−1)^1/2 ??

Comment: @ChanceGordon Bingo. Well, actually it is $1/(1-2t)^{1/2}$ (but that's my fault, see edit.)

Answer (score 1):

Moment generating function of $X\sim N(0,1)$ is by definition
$$M_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{tx} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}2} \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2-2tx}2} \, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-t)^2+t^2}2} \, dx=$$
$$=e^{\frac{t^2}2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-t)^2}2} \, dx=e^{\frac{t^2}2}$$
since the final integral equals one (why?).

But you actually need to find the moment generating function of $X^2$, so you need
$$M_{X^2}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{tx^2} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}2} \, dx.$$
Try to put both exponentials in one and try a change of variables.

You can also calculate $F_{X^2}(t)=P(X^2\le t)$. First consider the cases $t<0$ and $t=0$, which will return zero probability, and then work the case $t>0$ to relate $F_{X^2}$ and $F_X$. You can then take derivatives to put the relation in terms of densities instead of cumulative distributions.

That is: try to prove that for $t>0$
$$F_{X^2}(t)=2 F_X(\sqrt t)-1.$$

If you take a derivative (with respect to $t$; I then evaluated in $t=x$ just for convention), it turns out that a pdf for $X^2$ is given by
$$f_{X^2}(x)=2 f_X(\sqrt x)\cdot \frac 1 {2\sqrt x},\quad x>0,$$
(and $0$ otherwise).

Now you just have to substitute $f_X$ by its actual formula to find that this is the density of a $\Gamma$ distribution for some specific parameter values.